# Populate ASP dropdownlist containing languages

Tags: javascript, c#, getelementbyid, cefsharp

I'm using Winforms, C#.

Running the latest CefSharp.

I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist, the website is made in ASP.net. I've tried it by simply modifying the value of the "Valuecontrol input", but this doesnt seem the be recognized as a input from the website, as you can see down below its the code.

There are two parts of code that belong together, below is the "Input Name"

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$tcModal$fd1b3735de9b4347a6a46e58310aab4a$8796dda4a9954a2eabf941375403b1b7_ValueControl" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="ctl00_MainContent_tcModal_fd1b3735de9b4347a6a46e58310aab4a_8796dda4a9954a2eabf941375403b1b7_ValueControl_Input" value="<Default>" readonly="readonly" autocomplete="off">
```

And here is the "input ID":

```
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_tcModal_5b3f462a46784a108cb31d3cfbbf71e7_f383f3809de14ac89ba9304b6922377d_ValueControl_ClientState" name="ctl00_MainContent_tcModal_5b3f462a46784a108cb31d3cfbbf71e7_f383f3809de14ac89ba9304b6922377d_ValueControl_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">
```

As soon as a select a language from the dropdown list there some code added to "Input ID", as seen below.

```
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_tcModal_5b3f462a46784a108cb31d3cfbbf71e7_f383f3809de14ac89ba9304b6922377d_ValueControl_ClientState" name="ctl00_MainContent_tcModal_5b3f462a46784a108cb31d3cfbbf71e7_f383f3809de14ac89ba9304b6922377d_ValueControl_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="{&quot;logEntries&quot;:[],&quot;value&quot;:&quot;Argentinian Spanish&quot;,&quot;text&quot;:&quot;Argentinian Spanish&quot;,&quot;enabled&quot;:true,&quot;checkedIndices&quot;:[],&quot;checkedItemsTextOverflows&quot;:false}">
```

So i've tried to modify the added part of code, but with no succes.

See my code:

```
document.getElementById(document.evaluate("/html/body/form/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/input", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.id).value = '{"logEntries":[],"value":"Bulgarian","text":"Bulgarian","enabled":true,"checkedIndices":[],"checkedItemsTextOverflows":false}'
```

[Raw code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6JzK.png)

Is there any other way i could do this?

Comment: You can modify the DOM using JavaScript see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration

Comment: Thanks it works! I'm trying to automate a website. Its a ASP website, I'm trying to fill in a dropdownlist to bad this doesnt work with getelememtbyid. Any idea how to populate a dropdownlist made in ASP? When changing the value of the dropdownlist it doesn't work.. how to do this with javasctipt?

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide an example of the html and what you have tried.

Comment: I've edited the original question! :)

Comment: Where is the dropdown list exactly?  I don't see any select element in your example?

Comment: I've added a picture of the code, maby its more clear now